# Input Validation function not working

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function to check if any text is entered in the email field but it is not working.
I am not sure what I am missing.

This is my Form:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    <form action="" id="contactInfo" onsubmit="checkform()">First Name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        <br />Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="laname">
        <br />Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

This is my function in a seperate `.js` file

```
function checkform(form) {
    if (document.form.email.value = "") {
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        document.form.email.focus();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Seeing you have a `form` parameter in your `checkForm` function you should pass it like this: `<form id="contactInfo" onsubmit="checkform(this)">` then you can simply use `form.email.value == ""` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbnbB/1/).

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    <form id="contactInfo" onsubmit="checkform()">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="laname"><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkform(form) 
{
    console.log(form);
    if(document.forms[0].email.value == ""){
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        document.form.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: just figured it out. I had not added the extra = sign. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
 document.forms[0].email.value
```

or use form ID to retrieve the value.

```
function checkform(form) {
    if (document.forms[0].email.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        document.forms[0].email.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/V49qL/)

Comment: I did this one but it still does not work. the debuggers gives me an error. it is TypeError:document.form is undefined

Comment: did you looked at the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the form in as the argument `this` to your `checkForm()` function. This way you can use the `checkForm()` function with multiple forms. Like so:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    <form action="" id="contactInfo" onsubmit="checkform(this)">First Name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        <br />Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="laname">
        <br />Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Then you can access the form element with out the `document.` prefix from your validation function like so:

```
function checkform(form) {
    if (form.email.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        form.email.focus();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

(Also, make sure you check `form.email.value == ""` not `form.email.value = ""` which is the assignment operator).